# How can i rewrite URL with PHP and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a news system with article and category.

```
Category: cat.php
id categoryname 
Article: index.php
```

id title content catid 
I have rewrite post and category like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+)-([a-z]+) index.php?id=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^cat-([0-9]+)-([a-z]+) cat.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

it will show something like this:

```
http://localhost/article-1

http://localhost/article-2


http://localhost/article-3

http://localhost/cat-1


http://localhost/cat-2
```

Now i want it show as

```
http://localhost/title-article (title of article)

http://localhost/categoryname (name of category instead of ID)
```

How can i do that?

Comment: create slug names title-article & categoryname & refer it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#This is for article Detail page
insert this line in your .htaccess file for defining rule.**

```
RewriteRule ^(article)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$3
RewriteRule ^(article)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$3
```

**after that while redirecting from some page to your article detail page you must redirect like this.**

```
<a href="http://localhost/article/pass article name-pass articleId" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but seem it does'nt work. It show me a 404 page. 
I try to change it to 

RewriteRule ^(article)-([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$3 
and it doesn't work too.
How about category? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This is what i get on address bar: http://localhost/article/-8 (My title is PHP MySQL news system and ID is 8)
And i also try: http://localhost/article--8

Comment: ya sure it will give 404 error page by this url localhost/article/-8 you are missing article name in url localhost/article/article name here-8

Comment: Mean i have to force add "article" to the link?
But i mean i want it as: localhost/php-mysql-news-system/ (general is localhost/my-article-title/ )

and i dont know how to rewrite category to localhost/category-name instead of localhost/cat-id

Comment: same way you can access it .

Comment: #This is for Business main category page
RewriteRule ^(category)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/$ category.php?catId=$3
RewriteRule ^(category)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ category.php?catId=$3